# Faunus test failed on com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec not found, HDP1.3

Tags: hadoop, lzo, titan

Hello I installed Faunus 0.32 on HDP 1.3 
When I follow the get-start test case in https://github.com/thinkaurelius/faunus/wiki/Getting-Started, 
I got following errors

```
    gremlin> g = FaunusFactory.open('bin/faunus.properties')
    ==>faunusgraph[graphsoninputformat->graphsonoutputformat]
    gremlin> g.V.type.groupCount
    13/09/29 21:38:49 WARN mapreduce.FaunusCompiler: Using the distribution Faunus job jar: lib/faunus-0.3.2-job.jar
    13/09/29 21:38:49 INFO mapreduce.FaunusCompiler: Compiled to 1 MapReduce job(s)
    13/09/29 21:38:49 INFO mapreduce.FaunusCompiler: Executing job 1 out of 1:     MapSequence[com.thinkaurelius.faunus.mapreduce.transform.VerticesMap.Map,   com.thinkaurelius.faunus.mapreduce.sideeffect.ValueGroupCountMapReduce.Map, com.thinkaurelius.faunus.mapreduce.sideeffect.ValueGroupCountMapReduce.Reduce]
    13/09/29 21:38:49 INFO mapreduce.FaunusCompiler: Job data location: output/job-0
    13/09/29 21:38:49 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
    13/09/29 21:38:50 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
    13/09/29 21:38:50 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://hadoop121.ctd.com:8020/user/root/.staging/job_201309292136_0003
Compression codec com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec not found.
Display stack trace? [yN] y
java.lang.RuntimeException: Compression codec com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec not found.
        at com.thinkaurelius.faunus.tinkerpop.gremlin.ResultHookClosure.call(ResultHookClosure.java:54)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:428)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.setLastResult(Groovysh.groovy:324)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.this$3$setLastResult(Groovysh.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2416)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3347)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.setProperty(Shell.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:528)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:152)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:114)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell$leftShift$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:88)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1079)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:100)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:57)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1079)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:148)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:66)
        at com.thinkaurelius.faunus.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.<init>(Console.java:54)
        at com.thinkaurelius.faunus.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.<init>(Console.java:61)
        at com.thinkaurelius.faunus.tinkerpop.gremlin.Console.main(Console.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Compression codec com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec not found.
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.getCodecClasses(CompressionCodecFactory.java:96)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.<init>(CompressionCodecFactory.java:134)
        at com.thinkaurelius.faunus.formats.graphson.GraphSONInputFormat.isSplitable(GraphSONInputFormat.java:33)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1041)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:959)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:912)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:912)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:500)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530)
        at com.thinkaurelius.faunus.mapreduce.FaunusCompiler.run(FaunusCompiler.java:322)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
        at com.thinkaurelius.faunus.FaunusPipeline.submit(FaunusPipeline.java:1075)
        at com.thinkaurelius.faunus.FaunusPipeline.submit(FaunusPipeline.java:1058)
        at com.thinkaurelius.faunus.tinkerpop.gremlin.ResultHookClosure.call(ResultHookClosure.java:38)
        ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:802)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.getCodecClasses(CompressionCodecFactory.java:89)
        ... 75 more
```

I google it, and add the lzo in mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>io.compression.codec.lzo.class</name>
<value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I tried several methods, but none of them are working
1. disable output compression mapred.output.compress=false;
2. put lzo library liblzo2.so in native directory /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64; 
3. use HDP default SnappyCodec in bin/faunus.properties,  mapred.output.compression=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec

please help me out, I really want to use Faunus features

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the temp solution. It's kind of HDP bug, which was reported by 2-3 persons.

hadoop-lzo-0.5.0.jar  is in hadoop lib folder,  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/

And I do have CLASSPATH =  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/

However, it can not find the lzo library.

My temp fix is to copy hadoop-lzo-0.5.0.jar  to faunus lib folder, which in my env it is /root/faunus-0.3.2/lib

Then it works.

Hopefully, my notes can help other ppl who encountered the same problem.

```
gremlin> g = FaunusFactory.open('bin/faunus.properties')
==>faunusgraph[graphsoninputformat->graphsonoutputformat]
gremlin> g.V                                            
13/09/30 21:57:51 WARN mapreduce.FaunusCompiler: Using the distribution Faunus job jar: lib/faunus-0.3.2-job.jar
13/09/30 21:57:51 INFO mapreduce.FaunusCompiler: Compiled to 1 MapReduce job(s)
13/09/30 21:57:51 INFO mapreduce.FaunusCompiler: Executing job 1 out of 1: MapSequence[com.thinkaurelius.faunus.mapreduce.transform.VerticesMap.Map]
13/09/30 21:57:51 INFO mapreduce.FaunusCompiler: Job data location: output/job-0
13/09/30 21:57:51 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/09/30 21:57:52 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/09/30 21:57:52 INFO lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Loaded native gpl library
13/09/30 21:57:52 INFO lzo.LzoCodec: Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev cf4e7cbf8ed0f0622504d008101c2729dc0c9ff3]
13/09/30 21:57:52 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
13/09/30 21:57:52 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
13/09/30 21:57:52 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
13/09/30 21:57:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201309302049_0010
13/09/30 21:57:54 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
```